# running images in a loop using roslaunch

Tags: ros, roslauch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have few images which I wanted to run using roslaunch command. Unfortunately, the images doesn't loop itself.
Is there a way to loop images in ROS using roslaunch?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239869/running-images-in-a-loop-using-roslaunch/) by [xploderz22](https://answers.ros.org/users/27546/xploderz22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

You could write a node that publishes your images one after the other and then launch that node from a launch file.

To do that you can probably follow [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/PublishingImages) and modify it to loop through your images.

I haven't tested any of this but I guess you would have to change   `cv::Mat image = cv::imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);`
to something like :

`cv::Mat image1 = cv::imread(path/to/image1, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);`

`cv::Mat image2 = cv::imread(path/to/image2, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);`

`cv::Mat image3 = cv::imread(path/to/image3, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);`

and then change `msg` at a regular time interval in the loop

---

Originally posted by [jbb](https://answers.ros.org/users/27481/jbb/) with karma: 16 on 2016-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0